# Backbone change event not fired for select field selected by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a button that when clicked sets the value of a select field and also have a change event for the select field. The 'change select[name=location_id]' event works when selecting normally via mouse/keyboard but clicking the button, which uses jQuery to change the select field value, doesn't fire off the 'change select[name=location_id]' event.

How do I get the 'change select[name=location_id]' to fire when changing the field via jQuery?

```
SubscriptionsModule.Views.SubscriptionEditView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "subscriptions/edit",
    events: {
      'click #home-delivery-select': 'selectHomeDeliverySite',
      'change select[name=location_id]': 'updateLocation'
    },
    selectHomeDeliverySite: function() {
      this.$el.find('select[name=location_id]').val(this.model.get('hd_location_id'));
    },
    updateLocation: function(e) {
      //update location code
    },
    updateOrderSize: function(e) {
      SubscriptionsModule.eventManager.trigger('updateOrderSize', $(e.currentTarget).data('price'));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to add an event:

```
this.$('select[name=location_id]').val(this.model.get('hd_location_id')).trigger('change');
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't trigger a change even when setting a value using `val()`, so in order for backbone to be able to listen that event, we have to programmatically trigger it. It's not really documented in the jQuery docs but it is how it behaves.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Also, please disregard the below answer, since as per the [MDN `input` event docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), the `input` event only fires for `<input>` and `<textarea>` and will not fire for `<select>`, since the `value` of `<select>` doesn't change when any of its options are selected (btw, `<input>` with `type` *checkbox* or *radio* will also not emit an `input` event  since their `value` attribute is not changed on selection(*!*).

I'll leave the answer up for reference.

---

## The following is incorrect

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)**

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the **input event**, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.

According to [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html), the `change` event is buggy for all IE and Opera.

Try replacing

```
'change select[name=location_id]': 'updateLocation'
```

with

```
'input select[name=location_id]': 'updateLocation'
```

Comment: I was hoping this would work but it looks like the input event only works for <input> and <textarea> elements. <select> got left out! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: No it does not. I just tested it... You're completely right. Thank you for looking that up!

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the change event on backbone after you change something with jquery you need to trigger the change event.

`elem.trigger('change')`

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/